# flutter_local_notifications not working on ios, but working on android

Tags: flutter

If I use the show() method of the FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin then I get a notification on Android but not on ios.

```
showNotification(
    String notificationId, String title, String body, String payload) async {
  final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
          "important-notifications",
          tr("DEVICE.IMPORTANT_NOTIFICATIONS_NAME"),
          tr("DEVICE.IMPORTANT_NOTIFICATIONS_DESCRIPTION"),
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          ledColor: Colors.pink,
          ledOffMs: 50,
          ledOnMs: 50,
          color: Colors.purple,
          styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(""),
          ticker: 'ticker');

  final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
  );
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: payload);
}
```

The solution to this problem is below.

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem with **platform specifics** in the **flutter_local_notifications** plugin.

For example, if you use

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          .createNotificationChannel(channel);
```

inside of your local notification initialization function, then the function will stop at this point if you're not on an android device. This results in not initializing the plugin with ios + android settings.

**Solution**
To fix this just wrap everything you do with .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation into a platform check

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          .createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
if (Platform.isIOS) {
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
              IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          .requestPermissions(
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true,
          );
    }
```